# Вывод изображений с кастомным размером в WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, acf

Использую плагин Advanced Custom Fields

Вот код вывода изображений

```
<?php while(have_rows('flat_thumb')): the_row(); ?>
$flatThumbImage=get_sub_field('flat_thumb_image');
$size = 'miniature_card';
?>
 <img src="<? echo $flatThumbImage['sizes'][$size]; ?>">
<?  endwhile; ?>
```

В functions.php размер изображений задается вот так

```
add_image_size( 'miniature_card', 395, 245, false );
```

Но картинка не обрезается и выводится в полном размере. Как вывести картинку только с заданными размерами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код верный, но для картинок, которые были загружены раньше создания нового размера 'miniature_card' , будет возвращаться оригинал

Нужно запустить перегенерацию картинок - например, плагин [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)